# How do I install the Stellar app on my Ledger Nano S

Tags: wallets, ledger, ledger-nano

I just received my Ledger Nano S and understand that it has support for Stellar. What is the procedure to install the app on this device?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's explained well in ledger support center [here](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003797194-How-to-install-and-use-Stellar-)

> - Launch the Ledger Manager ([click to see how to install and use it if you don't have it installed yet](https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005173209))
> - Connect your Nano S, enter your PIN, and stay on the dashboard
> - On the ledger manager, scroll down and click on the green bottom arrow icon near the Stellar logo
>     [image]
> - Confirm the installation if required on your device
> - Quit the Ledger Manager
>
> *If you read "Unable to install application" error message on your Ledger Manager it can be displayed for several issues described here.*

Comment: I just went through this process. The points above are all correct, but I was missing the key part of changing the settings ON THE LEDGER itself. You have you make your Stellar wallet "Accessible by Browser".